# Why won't this string regex match?

Tags: java, regex

I have a string and a simple pattern (a string with a wildcard). When I use the `match` function I would it expect it to return `true` for my text, but it doesn't it returns false.

```
String text = "test_1_2_3";
String pattern = "test_*"

text.matches(pattern);//this returns false
```

Comment: * means "any #occurences of the previous", not "whatever may follow". As Kasra suggests, the correct pattern is "test_.*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_*`  will matches the character `_` literally [between zero and more times](https://regex101.com/r/eR6cC0/2) ,instead you need `.*` that match any character between zero and more times:

```
"test_.*"
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eR6cC0/1)

Comment: correct, because `.` means "any character" and `.*` means "any character as many times as it appears"

Comment: @vefthym Yeah indeed ;)

Answer (score 1):

`pattern = "test_*"` means `"test"` and 0 or more `"_"`

Answer (score 1):

Because your `test_*` pattern, combined with `Matcher#matches`, will match a **whole** input (i.e. from start to end), that matches the following conditions:

- starts with `test`
- followed by (and ending with) **0** instance of `_`, or more (greedy-quantified here).

Using `Matcher#find` would return `true` in this case, since it would match a partial `test_`.

So, your `matches` invocation would return `true` with the given `Pattern`, with inputs such as:

- `test_`
- `test__`
- ... and so on.

See [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Comment: '*' looks for 0 or more, what you mean is '?'

Answer (score 0):

Your regexp will match test followed by zero or more '_' character.
I think you want this:

```
String text = "test_1_2_3";
String pattern = "test_.*";
```